# Can't add node in circular linked list if nodes are made without the function

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

1. I need to add a node at the start of the circular linked list
2. I can add the node if the list is empty and I add every node using the function but if the list already has nodes then the function doesn't work

```
class Node:
       def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None

class CircularLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def atStart(self,newData):
        newNode = Node(newData)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
            self.tail.ref = newNode
        
        if self.tail:
            newNode.ref = self.tail.ref
            self.tail.ref = newNode

    def printList(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Circular linked list is empty")
        n = self.head
        while n:
            print(n.data)
            n = n.ref
            if n == self.head:
                break


cll = CircularLinkedList()
cll.head = Node("Monday")
e2 = Node("Tuesday")
e3 = Node("Wednesday")

cll.head.ref = e2
e2.ref = e3
e3.ref = cll.head
cll.atStart("Sunday")
cll.atStart("Monday")
cll.printList()
```

3. I need to change the `head` node using the `atStart` function and print the whole list but it prints the three nodes I have made (cll.head,e2,e3) or just the newNode using the `atStart` if list is empty

I tried debugging and seems like whenever the list is not empty it only takes the newNode data and doesnt set the `ref` of it `head` node and just prints the old three nodes

Comment: If you read the description of the [tag:dsa] tag, it says "Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions."

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. You're not supposed to mess with nodes "by hand", but use the `CircularLinkedList` interface exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

- In `atStart` the `if self.tail:` condition will **always** be true. This is problematic, as only one of the two alternatives should be executed, not both. Yet when the first block executes (the case where the list was empty), `self.tail` gets a value, so this second `if` block will *also* execute (the case where the list is not empty). This should not be an `if`, but just a plain `else:` -- you want to cover all remaining cases (where the list was not empty).
- In the case the list was not empty, the `atStart` method does not make the new node the head of the list, so the list becomes inconsistent.
- The main program should not tinker with the `head` or `ref` attributes -- this should be left to the class code only. This leads to all kinds of problems. In this case the problem is that `cll.tail` remains `None`, and so the list is inconsistent and you cannot rely on the correct execution of the `atStart` method, because that assumes that `tail` was set correctly. You could add `cll.tail = e3` to fix that particular issue, but again, this is bad practice. The logic for attaching nodes to eachother should be performed within the class code only.

Not a problem, but it is overkill for a circular list to have *two* node references (head and tail): in a non-empty list the head *always* follows the tail node, so there really is no need to remember what the head is when you have the tail. In short: just keep track of the tail.

Here is the adapted code:

```
class Node:
       def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None

class CircularLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        # No need for a head reference, as it is always coming after the tail
        self.tail = None

    def atStart(self,newData):
        newNode = Node(newData)

        if self.tail is None:
            self.tail = newNode
        else:  # Must be ELSE to avoid executing both blocks
            newNode.ref = self.tail.ref
        self.tail.ref = newNode  # new node always becomes the head

    def printList(self):
        if self.tail is None:
            print("Circular linked list is empty")
        n = self.tail.ref
        while n:
            print(n.data)
            if n == self.tail:
                break
            n = n.ref
```

The main program corrected:

```
cll = CircularLinkedList()
# Don't alter the atttributes of the linked list or its nodes! Only use methods:
cll.atStart("Wednesday")
cll.atStart("Tuesday")
cll.atStart("Monday")
cll.printList()
print("----")
cll.atStart("Sunday")
cll.atStart("Monday")
cll.printList()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-linked-list/):

> The circular linked list is a linked list where all nodes are
> connected to form a circle. In a circular linked list, the first node
> and the last node are connected to each other which forms a circle.
> There is no NULL at the end.

```
def atStart(self,newData):
        if self.head is None:
            # Initialize head and tail
            newNode = Node(newData)
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            # Copy the old head node
            old_head = self.head
            # Make a new head node
            self.head = Node(newData)
            # Update the reference of the new head node to point the old_head
            self.head.ref = old_head
            # Now update the tail ref to point to the head (circular)
            self.tail.ref = self.head
```

Explanation:

In this code if head and tail are empty, for the the first call of `atStart` method the head and tail will be the same, that's `self.head is self.tail` which evaluates to `True`. It's possible to implement this code a better way, where for example `__init__` or `atStart` methods should except two values instead of one to initialize the head and tail together. Because in this way, the data of the head will reside in the tail uselessly even after adding a new head. If you call this:

`cll.head.data == cll.tail.data`

Now it's interesting what you will get. The first call to `atStart` method will evaluate to `True`, the second call may not evaluate to true. That's, whatever the first `cll.head.data` held will be there in `cll.tail.data` always. Effectively we're wasting `cll.tail.data`.

A better approach would be

```
def atStart(self, *newData):
            if self.head is None:
                # Initialize head and tail (each with its own data)
                self.head = Node(newData[0])
                self.tail = Node(newData[1])
                # tail references head (circular)
                self.tail.ref = self.head
                #rest of code from above....
```

The second call to the `atStart` method will update the head of the circular list to point to the new head node (created to add the last value) and the tail reference will be updated to point back to the new head. Note that the `ref` attribute of the new head will be updated to reference the *old* head, it's a very important step or you will end up losing your old data.

Comment: since `self.head is self.tail` why is anything wasted?

Comment: @JonSG I need to be clear that the fact that `self.head is self.tail` is not the point where the waste is happening. But the waste is happening as the `self.tail.data` attribute will always be the same as the _first_ head's `data` attribute. To experiment with this: `cll.atStart("Saturday"); cll.atStart("Sunday"); cll.atStart("Monday")` . Check `cll.tail.data` it will be `Saturday`. This is especially important if `data` of the first head is a mutable object like a `list` where changes are reflected on all references. A singly circular linked list is where the tail has a reference to the head.